# Calculating the Last yearYTD

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get the Last year YTD, My report looks some thing like this:

[image]

Last Year YTD pops up all Nulls,What am I doing wrong? in this.

[.twbx Attachment](http://www.filedropper.com/lastyearsales)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this field?

Comment: @Inox : YTD(year to date) the field should contain data between dates,example date between `01012013` and `now()`

Comment: but the display format should be as above

Comment: Okay, so why don't you just do SUM(IF [Order Date] > [custom date] THEN [Sales] END ?